# Most efficient way to implement matrix on large inputs in c++?

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, vector

I am trying to figure out the best way to create a matrix in C++. So far I have two options I have come up with:

1) One vector which stores all the data in one "line," but using modulo and arithmetic, can be accessed like a 2D table.

OR

2) A vector holding pointers to other vectors, such that the original vector represents set columns and the vectors it points to contain the values going down the rows of each column.

For example, if we have a table like so:

```
Name  |  Course   |  Grade
Allen | Chemistry |  76
Rick  | English   |  84
Mary  | Physics   |  93
```

My first example would store all the data in one vector like this:

```
my_vec = {Name, Course, Grade, 
          Allen, Chemistry, 76, 
          Rick, English, 84, 
          Mary, Physics, 93}
```

(assume the heterogeneous nature of the values stored in the same vector is not a problem for now)

My second example would store the data like so:

```
vec1 = {Name, Course, Grade};
```

Where each spot would contain a pointer to a vector (3 "sub" vectors in this ex.)

```
Name -> name_vec = {Allen, Rick, Mary}
Course -> course_vec = {Chemistry, English, Physics}
Grade -> grade_vec = {76, 84, 93}
```

Some requirements on the matrix:

- It needs to be growable, which is why I have elected to use vectors in my examples.
- It needs to be able to handle large amounts of data efficiently
- It must be able to support row insertion (at the end), row deletion (from the middle), appending one matrix to another (by adding its columns onto the left end of the original matrix, if we visualize it like a table)

Does anyone know if one of these options would be significantly more efficient than the other on large inputs? Alternately, does anybody have a better suggestion for implementing this matrix?

Comment: You can check Boost.uBLAS. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html

Comment: Are you looking to optimize mainly for speed or memory?

Comment: I usually use a straight vector for that, and do my own subscript calculations. For heterogenous data, I'd probably use a vector of pointers. Other options might be more appropriate if you have a lot of empty cells (sparse matrix) and need to optimize memory.

Comment: @flatmouse I am hoping to find a good medium between speed and memory, although I think speed is more important

Comment: If you assume heterogeneous data, why don't you consider a `vector` of `struct`s?

Comment: @Bob__ I have already handled the issue of heterogeneous data. It is more the performance I am concerned with at the moment

Comment: `"Most efficient way to implement matrix"` - to do what? Efficient solution for one operation can affect efficiency of another.
What will you do with this matrix after you've populated it? Looking up all grades for one name? Or averaging all grades for one course? Would you ever need this collection sorted? By what?

Comment: @VladFeinstein I would need to be able to add and delete entire rows, as well as print a row based on the value in one of its columns

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the main issue is good cache usage.  There isn't a huge win for using modulo arithmetic vs pointers for accessing the rows, but keeping the data in contiguous memory is very important for efficient access.  A vector of vectors is probably not going to be the most efficient because the individual vectors could be scattered throughout memory, unless you use a custom allocator.  A vector of pointers which point to sections of one contiguous block of elements is probably better.

The details about how to lay out your data is going to depend on your particular usage patterns though.  Where performance is concerned, you always need to measure.

Comment: Would the "one vector" method be preferable to the other when concerning the process of deleting a row in the middle of the matrix, because of better cache efficiency?

Comment: @user5482356: Modern CPUs are very good at moving large blocks of contiguous memory, so it may not be as bad as you think.  However, if row deletions are very common, you may end up better off manipulating row pointers rather than moving the elements.

Comment: @VaughnCato, what do you mean by cpu is good at moving memory? What exactly can cpu do here?

Comment: @SergeyA: The CPU can detect that you are accessing memory sequentially and prefetch:  http://www.futurechips.org/chip-design-for-all/prefetching.html

Comment: @VaughnCato, could you please elaborate on significance of *modern cpus* prefetch technique for memory move operation, taking into account the fact that memory moves are customary done through specific CPU instustions and you do not need *modern* cpu for `rep; movsb`?

Comment: @SergeyA: My point is about the relative speed of copying memory vs. using more sophisticated data structures to try to reduce the amount of copying that is done.  Techniques like prefetch have made copying faster while not improving the speed of random access.